# Портачит обработчик событий в джанго, помогите разобраться

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Вот мои модели:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import time



    # Create your models here.
    
    class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='owner')
        allowed_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class Lesson(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        link = models.URLField()
        time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class UserLessons(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        is_view = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        view_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        date_view = models.DateField(null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} - {self.lesson.name}'
```

Я реализую обработчик событий, который должен создавать запись в БД при создании записи Lesson

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Lesson)
def create_user_lessons(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    products = instance.products.all()
    allowed_users = []
    for product in products:
        for user in product.allowed_users.all():
            if user not in allowed_users:
                allowed_users.append(user)
    for user in allowed_users:
        UserLessons.objects.create(user=user, lesson=instance)
```

Но столкнулся с тем, что `instance.products.all()` выдает пустой QuerySet, хотя при создании записи он не пустой.
В чем причина такого поведения и как это решить?

Comment: Попробывал переопределить метод save(), но это никоем образом не помогло, но появилось важное уточнение, instance.products.all() выдает пустой qs только для записи, которая была создана в данный момент, остальные записи - работают в полной мере, при выборе другой все сохраняется как нужно

Answer (score 0):

После дня мучений смог разобраться, чтобы использовать обработчик с manytomany нужно юзать: m2m_changed

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Lesson.products.through)
def create_user_lessons_if_create_lesson_or_add_product_in_lesson(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set,
                                                                  **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        allowed_users = set()
        for product in instance.products.all():
            for user in product.allowed_users.all():
                allowed_users.add(user)
        for user in allowed_users:
            # If the object is not found, then we create it, otherwise - if it is created, then there are no actions to get rid of duplicates
            try:
                UserLessons.objects.get(user=user, lesson=instance)
            except:
                UserLessons.objects.create(user=user, lesson=instance)
```